# How can I return a string between two other strings in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have a string for a page source already created.  I need to grab a few lines of text from the string.  The string I need is between two other strings.  These two strings are **"keywords":** and **", "**

How would I search for a string that has a colon after the quotations such as **"keywords":**
?

Would I use regex?

Thank you.

Comment: Show an example of what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, regex is too powerful to use it with such a problem. Just use `string.IndexOf()` and `string.Substring()`. Get a position of the word, get a position of the closest comma - there is an overload for this in IndexOf that let you specify starting position of searching.

Here is a code snippet, it is more explaining then I could do it in words.

```
var text = "\"keywords\":some text you want,and a text you do not want";
var searchFor = "\"keywords\":";
int firstIndex = text.IndexOf(searchFor);
int secondIndex = text.IndexOf(",", firstIndex);
var result = text.Substring(firstIndex + searchFor.Length, secondIndex - searchFor.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following Regex will match everything between "keywords" and ",":

```
Regex r = new Regex("keywords:(.*),");
Match m = r.Match(yourStringHere);

foreach(Group g in m.Groups) {
    // do your work here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, without using Regex

```
    string str = "This is an example string and my data is here";
    string first =  "keywords:";
    string second = ",";
    int Start, End;
    if (str.Contains(first) && str.Contains(second))
    {
        Start = str.IndexOf(first, 0) + first.Length;
        End = str.IndexOf(second, Start);
        return str.Substring(Start, End - Start);
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: What is "getBetween", as far as I know its no commnon method within .NET

Comment: @HimBromBeere it was a method written, which is not used in my current code...

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work across multiple lines.

```
string input = @"blah blah blah ""keywords"":this is " + Environment.NewLine + "what you want right?, more blah...";
string pattern = @"""keywords"":(.*),";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (match.Success)
{
    string stuff = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```